# How to append a text containing pipe symbol with text file using command prompt?

Tags: command-prompt

I am trying to create a powershell script to a directory using batch file.

```
echo $ie=new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application" >> C:\scripts\IEAutomate.ps1
echo $ie.navigate("http://google.com") >> C:\scripts\IEAutomate.ps1
echo $ie.visible=$true >> C:\scripts\IEAutomate.ps1
echo sleep 10 >> C:\scripts\IEAutomate.ps1
echo $doc=$ie.document >> C:\scripts\IEAutomate.ps1
echo if (Test-Path (c:\scripts\username.txt)) >> C:\scripts\IEAutomate.ps1
echo { >> C:\scripts\IEAutomate.ps1
echo } >> C:\scripts\IEAutomate.ps1
else >> C:\scripts\IEAutomate.ps1
echo { >> C:\scripts\IEAutomate.ps1
echo $credential=Get-Credential >> C:\scripts\IEAutomate.ps1
echo $credential.Username | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Set-Content   c:\scripts\username.txt >> C:\scripts\IEAutomate.ps1
echo $credential.Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Set-Content c:\scripts\password.txt >> C:\scripts\IEAutomate.ps1
echo } >> C:\scripts\IEAutomate.ps1
```

It is creating fine but when I am trying to write a line which has pipe symbol (|), It is not happening and treating that as a cmdlet.

Please help me to get this done.

Answer (score 2):

Pipe symbol | is interpreted as a special character. For printing it you can exploit the escape character: ^

e.g.,:

```
echo ^|
```

or in your case

```
echo $credential.Username ^| [...]
```

Comment: best solution for pipe

Answer (score 1):

Insert a caret (`^`) before the pipe.

This is a standard solution to any of batch's special characters - except `%` which requires to be escaped with `%` (ie. double-up)

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping the pipe with a caret!

```
echo hi ^| joe > fred
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this URL to escape certain characters in powershell 3.0+.

To do what you need to do you need a caret, but in the link below it explains escaping.

http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-esc.html